# What is this mathematical equation from Fringe?

Tags: popular-math

The following mathematical equation was shown during the television show *[Fringe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fringe_%28TV_series%29)* which aired on Friday, April 22nd. Any idea what it is?

[image: Fringe formula]

(edit by J.M.: for reference, this was [Sam Weiss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fringe_characters#Sam_Weiss) scribbling formulae in his notebook.)

Comment: I haven't watched: was that Walternate writing?

Comment: I appreciate this question. I think it's fun and lively - what is Fringe?

Comment: @mix: [This TV show](http://www.televisionwithoutpity.com/show/fringe/).

Comment: @J.M. : No, it was that bowling guy. He was observing a vortex and taking notes.

Comment: @Gunnar: Thanks! I won't be able to watch until tomorrow, that's why I asked. :)

Comment: *adds popular-math to followed tags*... +1

Comment: Just a minor off topic of somewhat similar pop culture references: in the 21st episode of The Simpsons (season 22) there are the Kepler's laws of motion scribbled on a blackboard in two scenes. Pretty neat.

Comment: @BBischof, ditto.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The last formula seems to be an integral expression for the [Dirichlet $\eta$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletEtaFunction.html):

$$\eta(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^s}\quad \Re(s) > 0$$

Using the relationship with the usual Riemann $\zeta$ function

$$\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$$

and [this integral expression](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.5.E3), you get that integral in the notebook:

$$\eta(s) = \frac1{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x+1}\mathrm dx$$

There is also [this](http://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/Zeta/07/01/01/0002/) closely related integral (which Arturo mentions in his answer).

The (first part of the) second line looks to be the chain of relations relating Riemann $\zeta$, Dirichlet $\eta$, and [Dirichlet $\lambda$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletLambdaFunction.html):

$$\frac{\zeta(s)}{2^s}=\frac{\lambda(s)}{2^s-1}=\frac{\eta(s)}{2^s-2}$$

In the second part, the expressions look to be the differentiation of Dirichlet $\eta$, but the screenshot is fuzzy around that region...

Comment: Ok. Now that I look closely, it is a $e^x +1$, not a $e^x-1$. +1.

Comment: A confession: I was actually looking at the left hand side, and it sure looked like an $\eta$ to me... as for the equations on the second line, check out formula 3 in the MathWorld link I gave.

Comment: It is quite hard to read the second line, so I actually ignored those. Now that you point out, it does look like Eqn (3) :-)

Comment: Given the R(s) > 1/2 above that last integral, I wonder if the show was trying to show him solving (or attempting to solve) the Riemann Hypothesis...

Comment: The succeeding scene had Sam writing a 0 after the =, so I suppose yes.

Answer (score 15):

By sheer coincidence, this equation occurs in P. Mark Kayll's paper *Integrals don't have anything to do with discrete Math, do they?* (Mathematics Magazine **84** no. 2, April 2011, pages 108-119, doi:[10.4169/math.mag.84.2.108](http://dx.doi.org/10.4169/math.mag.84.2.108), which I was reading through today.  It is equation (6) on page 111.

$\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function,
$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^s}.$$

$\Gamma(s)$ is the Gamma function,
$$\Gamma(s) = \int_0^{\infty} t^{s-1}e^{-t}\,dt.$$

$R(s)\gt \frac{1}{2}$ says that the real part of $s$ is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$.

The final equation is just a recasting of the equality
$$\zeta(x)\Gamma(x) = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^{x-1}}{e^t-1}\,dt$$
which holds whenever $\Gamma(x)$ is finite.

Nothing to get *too* excited about... unless you don't know what any of the symbols mean, which I suspect holds for a very large portion of the viewership of *Fringe*.

Comment: Actually it is $e^x + 1$, not $e^x -1$ (sure looked like that to me too!), so J.M's answer is more accurate. (And the symbol and $Re(s) \gt 1/2$ fit better for that I suppose).

Comment: Arturo, [the DOI doesn't seem to work](http://dx.doi.org/10.4169/math.mag.84.2.108). Maybe link to [JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/pss/10.4169/math.mag.84.2.108) instead?

Comment: @J.M., also available at http://www.umt.edu/math/reports/kayll/Karply-MMag-submit09.pdf

Comment: @lhf: Thanks! I shall read it now...

Comment: @Moron: Hmmm... I can see how it might seem like a $+$ rather than a $-$; but the vertical stroke seems much lighter than the rest.

Comment: @J.M. I suspect the doi has not been created yet; the issue *just* came out in the past couple of weeks.

Comment: @Arturo: I guess I was under the impression that the DOI guys are prompt... guess not. :)

Comment: @J.M. I did double check; this is the DOI listed on the bottom of the first page of the article.

Answer (score 4):

It's Riemann's zeta-function as a Mellin transform.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Mellin_transform

Comment: Oh, it's $+1$, not $-1$. And it's $\eta$, not $\zeta$...